# Contactos Error Argumento incorrecto en una llamada JDBC

Tags: java, archivo, jdbc

Estaba modificando mi codigo ya para finalizar y al hacer una prueba del funcionamiento nuevamente vi que no estaba guardando nada en mi base de datos y fue ahi que vi el error.

Supuse que era el metodo de Agregar y creo que efectivamente ese es el problema sin embargo no logro encontrar el problema, revise los placeholders y son la misma cantidad de parámetros entonces no se a que se deba, alguien que me ayude por favor :(

Cabe aclarar que ya me habia funcionado sin embargo no se que paso, no estaba modificando nada que tuviera que ver con esa parte.
Estoy usando NetBeans, base de datos de Access

Este es el codigo afectado:

```
    public void Agregar(String nombre, String apellido, String domicilio, String telefono, String email, String FechaNac, int edad, String genero, String sZodiacal, String PAnimeFav, FileInputStream fis, int longitud){
    Connection conexion = obtenerConexion();
    if(conexion != null){
        try{
            String query = "Insert into Contactos(Nombre, Apellido, Domicilio, Telefono, Email, FechaNac,"
                    + "Edad, Genero, SignoZodiacal, PAnimeFav, Foto) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            try(PreparedStatement instruccion = conexion.prepareStatement(query)){
                instruccion.setString(1, nombre);
                instruccion.setString(2, apellido);
                instruccion.setString(3, domicilio);
                instruccion.setString(4, telefono);
                instruccion.setString(5, email);
                instruccion.setString(6, FechaNac);
                instruccion.setInt(7, edad);
                instruccion.setString(8, genero);
                instruccion.setString(9, sZodiacal);
                instruccion.setString(10, PAnimeFav);
                instruccion.setBinaryStream(11, fis, longitud);
                instruccion.executeUpdate();
            }
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Metodos.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
            try{
                conexion.close();
            }catch(SQLException ex){
                login.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es el codigo de error:

```
SEVERE: null
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 Argumento incorrecto en una llamada JDBC
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:348)
    at murguia.hector.contactosdbs.Metodos.Agregar(Metodos.java:54)
    at murguia.hector.contactosdbs.Goku.JBAgregarActionPerformed(Goku.java:424)
    at murguia.hector.contactosdbs.Goku$5.actionPerformed(Goku.java:273)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Argumento incorrecto en una llamada JDBC
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.invalidArgument(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setBlobParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setBinStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:346)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Argumento incorrecto en una llamada JDBC
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 45 more
```

Si me ayudan les agradecería bastante, ya es lo ultimo que tengo que hacer :/

[image: Aqui esta la tabla de Access]

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías mostrar cómo está constituida tu tabla `Contactos`? Me refiero a mostrar de qué tipo es cada columna en dicha tabla. Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: Parece que intentas insertar un tipo de dato erróneo porque no coincide con lo que tienes definido en la tabla (por ejemplo almacenar letras en un campo numérico). Tal como comenta A.Cedano tienes que mandar la estructura de la tabla. Si es MySQL puedes hacerlo con esta query: SHOW CREATE TABLE Contactos;

Comment: Hola Hector, bienvenido, más allá de el problema de la llamada a la base, tu segundo `try`, no tiene su correspondiente `catch`, por lo que tu código te arrojará un error.

Comment: si te funcionaba revisa el historial local en tu IDE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL_ar5HGC6k

Comment: Gracias Ruslan. Ya intente cargar a las anteriores modificaciones de mi historial de mi IDE pero no me funciono :/ y ya cargue la tabla pero no veo nada raro

Comment: Prueba a cambiar esta línea `instruccion.setBinaryStream(11, fis, longitud);` por **`instruccion.setBlob(11, fis, longitud);`** Considera también hacer un `Clean and Build` del proyecto.

Comment: Dos preguntas: cual es la linea **54** que arroja el error (es **instruccion.setString(1, nombre);**?), está instanciada la variable **instruccion**?... no creo, ya que de estarlo, tendrías que recibir el error que te mencioné más arriba, de la falta del **catch**.